# Displaying symbol to specific attibute in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, symbology, fields-attributes, visualisation

I have a point shapefile, where I categorized my waypoints with attributes (schools, toilets, etc.) and I would like to display certain attributes with specific symbols.

How can this be done?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: User was last seen 6 years ago - so chances are low the OP sees your message. But you're completely right! And reminding other users to accept answers they get is never a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

In a first run, style your data using the `categorized` style on the attribute field.

Then you can change every category style to fit your individual needs. Not only the colour as the default style does, but also another symbol, or SVG.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the "rule based" under the Style option if you have a different colum for each attribute (if schools are in a different colum from toilets).

Answer (score 2):

To label your features enable "Label this layer with" in the Layer properties > Labels by selecting the specific column from your attribute table. Then there are several possibilities to format the labels.